# does TinyMCE supports other languages to compose HTML emails?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I have used Tiny mce once in a asp.net project and found it a very nice tool.

Here is requirement of composing HTML emails in languages other then English (Spanish, French, German and Arabic) in asp.net project.

Kindly guide me does tiny mce support languages  other then English ? Is it something tiny mce should be supporting or something will be required on client side to be installed ?

Thanks for your time and sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add on the html generated part from this editor, a header that says the language that the text are, just like you do on html pages. Then you add this html text to your html part of your email and send it.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=LanguageEncodingCode" />
    <body>
.............. paste here what you get from this html editors.............
    </body>
    </html>
```